# Pushori Java Programming Matrix

Tags: java, user-interface, matrix, merge

I'm trying to recreate the pushori puzzle game, my main problem lies with the next following issue. Every time the user needs to enter a token, lets call it "1" as the example down below it needs to somehow "merge" with the matrix's row where is placed at that moment.

Consider this, the token is at the left side of the matrix meaning that the user needs to press the right arrow key doing the "row merging" as:

```
  0 0 0 0       the 0s are the main game matrix,  0 0 0 0  after you place
  0 0 0 0       the number 1 is the element       0 0 0 0  it when the user
  0 0 0 0       that's going to enter in the      0 0 0 0  press the right 
1 0 0 0 0       row (3) from the left direction ->0 0 0 1  arrow key
```

That'd be the basic example, now the real problem lies when you have the next following:

```
  0 3 0 3       there are many tokens around      0 3 0 3  after you place
2 1 0 2 0       the matrix and when the user  ->  0 2 1 2  it when the user
  1 0 2 0       wants to input the next token     1 0 2 0  press the right 
  0 1 0 1       now it needs to behave like       0 1 0 1  arrow key
```

1 0 2 0 is the row (1) and the next token to be entered is the number 2, it also needs to merge all its elements to the right side of the row along with the new user input (the number 2) resulting 0 2 1 2 as the new row (1), i'm confused in this part because I have the next function for the LeftDirection input from a class Table with the current matrix however I'm stuck trying to think of a way to actually implement this feature

```
public void enterFromLeftDirection(int index,int actualRow){


    where index would be element from the Left Direction that needs to merge
    and actualRow would be actualRow from the matrix that the user is located
    however I don't get how I would be able to merge everything as I've already said


}
```

Any tips/advices would be highly appreciated! thanks in advance!

[Pushori](http://www.mindjolt.com/pushori.html) <- You can take a look of the game from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I gathered from the game, the easiest way to shift the row is... Well, it's hard to explain briefly - maybe some code will help:

```
// We will assume that grid is the name of the matrix in the Table object

public void enterFromLeft(int numToEnter, int row){

    for(int i = grid[row].length - 1; i > 0; i--){

        // Now we check if that spot is a 0 - if it is,
        // we need to shift another number over to fill the space

        if(grid[row][i] == 0){

            // Shifts the rightmost number to this spot by
            // iterating from right to left over the row to find a non-0 number

            for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){

                // Checks if the number is non-0 - and if it is, sets the
                // empty space to said number and sets the number to 0 -
                // This essentially moves the rightmost non-0 tile to the right.

                if(grid[row][j] != 0){

                    grid[row][i] = grid[row][j];
                    grid[row][j] = 0;

                    j = -1; // Ends the for loop

                }

            }

            // If grid[row][i] is still 0, it means that there were no non-0
            // numbers in the regular grid, we will need to fill that space
            // with numToEnter. If we do that, there will be no other numbers
            // we need to shift right, so we can end the loop.

            if(grid[row][i] == 0){

                grid[row][i] = numToEnter;

                i = -1; // To end the loop

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe it will work. For adding numbers from the right instead of the left, change the for loops to iterate the other way (and the numbers to exit the loop - replace `-1` with `grid[row].length + 1`).

If you have any questions, comment below. But now I need to go play some more pushori.

Comment: Haha yah! that's awesome, I was kind of thinking of something similar but I was creating a new array instead and assigning it to the currentRow but this seems way more appropiate! thanks man really appreciated!

Comment: Yeah - you could potentially create another array, but in general, if you can do it within the array, you should - it saves memory. That's probably not a problem, but its good practice anyways.